# why does change image onclick not work local on pc?

Tags: javascript

I have this little testscript which works fine when images are on the sever. 
But it does not work when images are local on my pc. (.html and images in the same folder ofcourse)

```
<img alt="" src="http://www.mywebsite.nl/images/markwhite.png" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()"  />

<script>

 function changeImage() {

    if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "http://www.mywebsite.nl/images/markwhite.png") 
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "http://www.mywebsite.nl/images/markgreen.png";
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "http://www.mywebsite.nl/images/markwhite.png";
    }
} 
</script>
```

So when testing locally on my desktop it does not work. Can somebody explain me this?

```
<img alt="" src="markwhite.png" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()"  />

<script>

function changeImage() {

    if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "markwhite.png") 
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "markgreen.png";
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "markwhite.png";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you running a server locally or just opening the file in a browser?

Comment: I am just opening the file in the browser because I thought it's only javascript, it must work also local on my pc.

Comment: Sound like a pathing issue. Have you use an inspector to see where the browser thinks the images are located

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

You are asking for the actual, full URI of the image, not the value that is stored in the `src` `attribute` of the `image` tag itself.

It works in your first (server side) example, because the value of the URI and the value in the `src` attribute happen to be the same.

In your first example:

```
src="http://www.mywebsite.nl/images/markwhite.png"
```

Both the `URI` and the `src` `attribute` would be: `http://www.mywebsite.nl/images/markwhite.png`.

However, in your second example:

```
src="markwhite.png"
```

The source (URI) would *not* be only the filename `markwhite.png`, but the complete path of your file system. For example, on Unix: `/home/user/me/photos/markwhite.png`, or on Windows: `c:\web\photos\markwhite.png`.

You can simply verify this by adding some debugging. 
Add a simple `console.log` to your JavaScript:

```js
   function changeImage() {
      if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "markwhite.png") 
        console.log(document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src);
       {
         document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "markgreen.png";
       }
      else 
       {
         document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "markwhite.png";
       }
  }
```

Where the line:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src);
```

Will output the complete source into you browsers JavaScript console. Even a simple `alert`, instead of a console.log, would suffice as well:

```js
alert(document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src);
```

### Solution

What you are looking for is simply the value of the source *attribute* rather then the full source itself. If you wish to only get an attribute of an element in vanilla JavaScript you can use the `getAttribute` getter. In your case, change your `.src` into `.getAttribute('src')`.

Thus this altered script would do the trick:

```js
   function changeImage() {
      if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").getAttribute(src) == "markwhite.png") 
       {
         document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "markgreen.png";
       }
      else 
       {
         document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "markwhite.png";
       }
  }
```

Comment: @nuet, happy to help. Glad my ramblings were clear :)